# Centered div fixed to the bottom with another centered div overlaying it

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

Im trying to using bootstrap and im not finding a way to get what i want. This is the example that Im trying to make:

[image]
It's a single page with a full background image. I was able to do that. Now, I cant do 2 things:

Make the div with opacity sticky to the bottom of the page and make the icons with that position, coming out of the div. 
Im trying to use absolute position and negative margin but its not working.

If you guys wanna see, my test page is here: http://ninabecker.hospedagemdesites.ws/dev/

Can somebody help me put the div fixed on the bottom and make the social icons with that position, half inside and half outside the div? Im really lost.

Comment: I was able to make it stick to the bottom and centralize the divs. But I cant get it to get resposive. It looks bad on small screens. Can someone give me a hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With minimal html/css changes you can do this

1) In template

```
<div class="container">      
  <div class="row force-to-bottom">
    <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-10 text-center pai-armazena-textos">
        <div class="row force-to-bottom2">
            <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 hidden-xs"></div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-md-10 text-center">
              <div class="guarda-redes">
                <ul class="lista_redes_sociais">
                  <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/ninabeckeroficial?fref=ts"><img src="facebook_icone.png" alt=""></a></li>
                  <li><a href="https://twitter.com/becker_nina"><img src="twitter_icone.png" alt=""></a></li>
                  <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com/becker_nina/?hl=pt-br"><img src="instagram_icone.png" alt=""></a></li>
                  <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=nina+becker&amp;oq=nina+becker&amp;gs_l=youtube.12...0.0.0.44994.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0...0.0...1ac..11.youtube."><img src="youtube_icone.png" alt=""></a></li>
                  <li><a href="https://open.spotify.com/artist/4HNWCD51r0ZgOkQGuxMgJV"><img src="spotify_icone.png" alt=""></a></li>
                  <li><a href="https://itunes.apple.com/br/artist/nina-becker/id258763927"><img src="itunes_icone.png" alt=""></a></li>
                  <li><a href="http://www.deezer.com/br/artist/1291202"><img src="deezer_icone.png" alt=""></a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 hidden-xs"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 armazena-textos text-left">
                CONTATO PARA SHOWS:<br>
                <b>Gabriela Haber</b><br>
                gabriela@sensaproducoes.com.br<br>
                55 21 98187-5464<br>
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 armazena-textos text-left">
                <br><b>Maria Clara Ferreira</b><br>
                mariaclara@sensaproducoes.com.br<br>
                55 21 96569-2113<br>
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 armazena-textos text-left">
                ASSESSORIA DE COMUNICAÇÃO:<br>
                <b>Mercedes Tristão</b><br>
                mercedes@sensaproducoes.com.br<br>
                55 11 3034-5051<br>
              </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

2) In styles

```
..other styles

.pai-armazena-textos {
   background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
   border-radius: 5px;
   filter: alpha(opacity=50);
   opacity: 1;
   padding-top: 15px;
   padding-bottom: 10px;
   zoom: 1;
}

.force-to-bottom2 {
  top: -20px;
  left:50%;
  margin-left:-50%;
  position:absolute;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.force-to-bottom {
  bottom: 2%;
  left:50%;
  margin-left:-50%;
  position:absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

@media (max-width:991px) {
    .force-to-bottom2 {
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        position: relative;
        margin-left: 0px;
    }
    .lista_redes_sociais li {
        padding: 10px;
    }
}
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcNFX.png)

[More about bootstrap responsive grid](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/overview/)

Comment: Thanks, that helped me.